# Locally build a jekyll site for github page on virtualbox guest, lost the layout while access from host

Tags: virtualbox, jekyll

Recently I tried to maintain my jekyll site of github page locally.
I use a ubuntu 15.04 as a virtualbox guest and everything work fine when I build the jekyll site and browse the site in the guest OS.  But when I tried to accessed the site from the host(windows 7) , **the site look like it losts the layout.**
  I enable the Nat(for guest connect to the outside) and Host-only(for guest connect to the host) network adapter in virtualbox network setting. So the host can ping or ssh to the guest by the ip address assigned by the virtualbox(192.168.56.101).

**I build the jekyll site with the command**

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

Then I opened the browser in the host to open the url
http://192.168.56.101:4000/
the result:
[image]

**But in the virtualbox guest, if I open http://0.0.0.0:4000/**
the result is:
[image]
Which is just I expect.

**My question is:**
How can I fix my workflow to let me browse the jekyll site in the virtualbox guest from the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the jekyll instance in the virtual box server, run Jekyll with the server IP.

```
Usage:

  jekyll serve [options]

Options:

   -H, --host [HOST]  Host to bind to
```

The virtual server IP you have is `192.168.56.101` so you need to serve the Jekyll instance at that ip to make it accesible from outside:

```
jekyll serve -H 192.168.56.101
```

Then it will be accessible at http://192.168.56.101:4000